# Hibernate criteria join with "and" condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have below entities with the its relationshipes

```
JobAddress - JobHeader jobHeader
JobHeader - List<Job> jobs
Job - JobHeader
ProjectPhaseAddress - Job job, ConstructionMetric cm, JobAddress jobAddress
ConstructionMetric - Job job
```

Trying to build a Hibernate Criteria for the below query. How to build criteria by joing more than one tabe with AND condition.

```
SELECT JA.* FROM JOB_ADDRESS JA
JOIN JOB_HEADER JH ON JH.ADDRESS_ID = JA.ADDRESS_ID
JOIN JOB J on J.J_HEADER_ID = JH.ID
JOIN PROJECT_PHASE_ADDRESS PPA ON PPA.ADDRESS_ID = JA.ADDRESS_ID AND   PPA.JOB_ID = J.ID
JOIN CONST_METRIC CM ON CM.ID = PPA.CONST_METRIC_ID AND CM.JOB_ID = J.ID
WHERE JH.ID = 125656
```

Comment: ProjectPhaseAddress  and Job has bidirectional relationship?

Comment: No.. , ProjectPhaseAddress has Job defined means project_phase_address table is having job_id column